# How to set a primery key in existing table

Tags: postgresql

Can i have a primery key with this DDL i created?

```
CREATE TABLE panama.panama_edge (
start_id float8 NULL,
"TYPE" text NULL,
end_id float8 NULL,
link text NULL,
start_date text NULL,
end_date text NULL,
sourceid text NULL,
valid_until text NULL);
```

i confuse to set a primery key, that start_id and end_id actually can be a primery or foreign key. anybody help me how to solved this case? thank you

Comment: Having an "id" with the data type `float` is extremely strange. Having that as the primary key is even weirder.

Comment: i dont know this DDL has created, it follow by ETL tool

Comment: To define `start_id` and `end_id`  as primary key, you add `, CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (start_id, end_id)` just before the last bracket. Foreign key is an other story where you need to refer to a foreign table and its own columns.

Comment: See [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altertable.html). Note: As posted none of your columns can be a Primary Key. Primary Key **must be** unique and not null. If all these column can legitimately be null, then you will need a to create  surrogate.